# R and Neo4J Connection

Tags: r, neo4j, connection

Trying to connect R to a Neo4j desktop database. The connection always fails.

Being done on Windows 10, with **Neo4J** version 5.5 and **R** version 4.2.2.

With neo4r I'm always getting a 503 error. I've tried turning off authorization but the change makes no difference.

The connection code looks like:

```
con <- neo4j_api$new(
  url = "http://localhost:7474",
  user = "neo4j", 
  password = "YYZ"
  )
```

With neo2j I tried the following connection:

```
graph <- startGraph(url ="http://localhost:7474/db/myDatabase/tx")
```

but I get the following error:

> Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
>   Network Er
> (right here) ------^

I'm wondering if I'm missing any steps? Does either of these programs need a custom configuration before the connection would work? Might there be a really good tutorial on how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Have you looked at this guide? https://neo4j-rstats.github.io/user-guide/connect.html#get-informations-about-the-connection

Comment: That Error line is pointing at a spot in the previous line. You need to include in your question the previous line.